# tcpreplay traffic not being seen in localhost with netcat

Tags: udp, netcat, tcpreplay

I have a pcap file that I modified with tcprewrite to set source and destination IP = 127.0.0.1, while the port numbers are different. I also set both mac addresses to 00:00:00:00:00:00 as I understand that comms over localhost ignore MAC. I made sure checksum was fixed.

When I run `tcpreplay -i lo test-lo.pcap` in one shell, and `tcpdump -i lo -p udp port 50001` in another, I see the traffic. Yet, when I try to view the traffic with `netcat -l -u 50001`, it sees nothing. Wireshark is capturing the traffic correctly.

Side note: I'm seeing the following warning when running tcpreplay on localhost:
`Warning: Unsupported physical layer type 0x0304 on lo.  Maybe it works, maybe it won't.  See tickets #123/318` That seems worrisome.

I'm asking because my own UDP listener code is also having the same problem as netcat and thought that maybe I'm missing something. Why would traffic be seen by tcpdump and wireshark, and not by netcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm asking because my own UDP listener code is also having the same problem as netcat and thought that maybe I'm missing something. Why would traffic be seen by tcpdump and wireshark, and not by netcat?

Look at [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) of the kernel packet flow from wikipedia:

[image]

As you can see, there are different places along the path where packets can be accessed. Wireshark uses `libpcap`, which uses an `AF_PACKET` socket to see packets. Your UDP listener, like netcat, uses regular user-space sockets. Let's highlight both on this image. Wireshark obtains packets via the red path, netcat via the purple one:

[image]

As you can see, there is a whole sequence of steps packets have to go through in the kernel to get to a local process socket. These steps include bridging, routing, filtering etc. Which step drops your packets? I don't know. You can try tweaking the packets and maybe you'll get lucky.

If you want a more systematic approach, use a tool like [dropwatch](https://github.com/nhorman/dropwatch). It hooks into the kernel and shows you counters of where the kernel drops packets.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That explains the disconnect. I tried building dropwatch but couldn't get it to find libreadline. So, there must be something in the packet that needs to be set differently in the pcap file.

Comment: Yeah, I remember running into some compilation issues too. There's information floating around the internet on how to build it.

Comment: @Cosmo Got it to compile and work on Ubuntu 20.04.2 (kernel 5.4.0). Here are the packages I had to install: `autoconf pkg-config libtool build-essential libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev  libreadline-dev libpcap-dev binutils-dev`

Comment: Thanks. I did have all those packages installed. What finally worked (as described in the `./configure --help` is to `export LIBS=-lreadline` in the shell before running ./configure. Strange it couldn't find that lib in /usr/local/lib

Comment: @Cosmo Glad it worked out. Hope dropwatch helps you figure out where the drops happen. The output can be tricky to understand.